# Extracting text after aria-label using css_selector

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, css-selectors

I am trying to extract "Verified account" from an element like this:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-label="Verified account" class="r-13gxpu9 r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-1xvli5t r-9cviqr r-dnmrzs r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr"><g><path d="M22.5 12.5c0-1.58-.875-2.95-2.148-3.6.154-.435.238-.905.238-1.4 0-2.21-1.71-3.998-3.818-3.998-.47 0-.92.084-1.336.25C14.818 2.415 13.51 1.5 12 1.5s-2.816.917-3.437 2.25c-.415-.165-.866-.25-1.336-.25-2.11 0-3.818 1.79-3.818 4 0 .494.083.964.237 1.4-1.272.65-2.147 2.018-2.147 3.6 0 1.495.782 2.798 1.942 3.486-.02.17-.032.34-.032.514 0 2.21 1.708 4 3.818 4 .47 0 .92-.086 1.335-.25.62 1.334 1.926 2.25 3.437 2.25 1.512 0 2.818-.916 3.437-2.25.415.163.865.248 1.336.248 2.11 0 3.818-1.79 3.818-4 0-.174-.012-.344-.033-.513 1.158-.687 1.943-1.99 1.943-3.484zm-6.616-3.334l-4.334 6.5c-.145.217-.382.334-.625.334-.143 0-.288-.04-.416-.126l-.115-.094-2.415-2.415c-.293-.293-.293-.768 0-1.06s.768-.294 1.06 0l1.77 1.767 3.825-5.74c.23-.345.696-.436 1.04-.207.346.23.44.696.21 1.04z"></path></g></svg>
```

I tried the following, which extracts the elements:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("svg[aria-label='Verified account']")
```

But after this, how can I extract the text "Verified account"?
This is the original website from which I am trying to extract the aria-label, which is the text I get from the verified account image:

```
https://twitter.com/jpmorgan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the value of the attribute by `value_of_css_property`.

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("svg[aria-label='Verified account']")
element.get_attribute("aria-label")
```